# What is `^` in Visual Studio Code key bindings notation on macOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax, shortcut, key-bindings, notation

I'd like to open Source Control with a keyboard shortcut.

From the tooltip I can see, that a shortcut exists: [tooltip shows the shortcut (^ shift G)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROQc9.png)

My problem: How do I type the caret character? On my keyboard it's (shift + 6). However this does not work for shortcuts.

Comment: Are you using a Mac? The Windows notation is Ctrl+Shift+G.

Comment: Yes, I use a Mac Book Pro

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: You hinted me to the solution. The caret (^) stands for the control key. If you write this as answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some environments `^` stands for the <kbd>Control</kbd> key. Visual Studio Code uses that notation on its MacOS version.

| macOS | Linux |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Integrated terminal] | [image: Integrated terminal] |